# [AngularJS][ui-router]: optional params in states in the middle of URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to have something like:

```
  .state('courses', {
    url: '/{?type}/courses',
  })
```

to make "type" optional.

We've found this [solution](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108):

```
  .state('courses', {
    url: '{type:(?:/[^/]+)?}/courses',
  })
```

**BUT**

When you enter you app directly by link you will get extra slash with type param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.state('courses', {
  url: '/:type/courses',
  params: {
    courses: {
      value: 'defaultType',
      squash: true
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks to a genius who suggested https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1501

Gosh, spent almost half of the day on that feature

Comment: The distilled docs for 'squash' are here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider (ctrl-f 'squash')  Sergiy, I'm curious about how you found that RFC?